# DataMember name property is ignored in webservice

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, datamember

In my project I have a view model City that is exposed by wcf.
One of the properties is named differently then the already exposed contract dictates.
Therefore I added the DataMember attribute and set the Name value like so:

```
<DataContract(Namespace:=ServiceNamespace)> _ 
Public Class City
    private mySelectedTranslation as String
    <DataMember(Name:="CityName")> _
    Public Property SelectedTranslation() As String
          Get
              Return mySelectedTranslation
          End Get
          Set (ByVal value As String)
              mySelectedTranslation = value
          End Set
      End Property
End Class
```

In my consuming test project the service reference doesn't seem to pick up on the DataMember attribute however and receives the SelectedTranslation property instead of the CityName property.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I found out that when I remove the ServiceContract's  `XmlSerializerFormat(Style:=OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)` setting, the datamember attribute is correctly used. I'm thinking the RPC XmlSerializer might be bugged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two default serializers for XML in WCF: the `DataContractSerializer` (DCS) and the `XmlSerializer`. The former understands attributes such as `<DataContract>` and `<DataMember>` (from the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace). The latter understands attributes from the System.Xml.Serialization namespace, such as `<XmlElement>`, `<XmlAttribute>`, etc. When you decorate your contract with `<XmlSerializerFormat>`, you're telling WCF to use the `XmlSerializer`, so it will ignore any of the DCS-specific attributes (DCS is the default).

If you want to change the element name while using the `XmlSerializer`, you can use the `<XmlElement>` attribute:

```
<XmlType(Namespace:=ServiceNamespace)> _
Public Class City
    private mySelectedTranslation as String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="CityName")> _
    Public Property SelectedTranslation() As String
          Get
              Return mySelectedTranslation
          End Get
          Set (ByVal value As String)
              mySelectedTranslation = value
          End Set
      End Property
End Class
```